# K map minimization need confirmation

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

So I have to solve this

f= ∑m(0,4,10,17,21,26,27,31)+ ∑d(1,5,7,8,11,16,19,20,23,24,25)

Please tell me if this is correct:

[image: kmap]

Comment: Is there a fifth variable you haven't told us about?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: E=0 for the left table, and E=1 for the right table.

Comment: @DaveTweed I assumed so, but I really wanted the OP to clean up their work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `m(...) + d(...)` notation, but I gather that the first list is "must be 1" and the second list is "don't care". In that case, you've got it nearly right, except for the last term, which need to take E into account.